# Simple php code in post method which request from web service

Tags: php, web-services

I am new to web services. I have tried to request from the example web service at http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx. This is the code I have tried:

```
<?php
    $data = array('Celsius' => '56');  

    $curl = curl_init('http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx
    /CelsiusToFahrenheit');

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit');  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: You haven't explained the issue you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but should the data be a query string

```
$data = "Celsius=56";
```

I am sure you are doing this just to test curl. You don't really need a webservice to convert celsius to farenheit

Comment: It's a POST request, so it shouldn't be a query string

Comment: i mean the data has to be encoded the same way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Comment: thanks for the replys. Just forget the code. you can see the webservice  http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx . plese guide me how to create a php request in http post method. i need the response in a variable. thanks

Comment: It works for me if I do what Somesh says and I remove the line break from the URL in `CURLOPT_URL` statement.

Comment: In fact, you don't need to specify the URL twice. You can do it either in the `init` or in the `setopt`, just make sure there are no line breaks.

Comment: yay I am right I am right :). Now show some love and press those upvote buttons. Don't be shy

Comment: @AnasFahumy Try making the changes ironcito suggested and see if it works. There's a link in my first comment

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee thanks alot for the link. I could solve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,count($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

Use these attibutes. to fetch the data. as some url requires exact parameters.

Note* :- Headers are optional